# Flex 4 spark - Best way to monitor change of a component's displaylist?

Tags: actionscript-3, displaylist

I'm working on a drag-drop solution, and acting when a item is dropped on the current target (let's say an "intelligent chess-board") is a breeze, as the board fires DragEvents when items are hovering over on dropped on the it.

What I'm looking for is a way to make the board act when an item is dragged OFF the itself. Of course - when the item is dropped somewhere else, I could fire an event there and tell the board that change has been done. But this is what I want to avoid.

I wonder if there is some way to monitor a change in the displaylist of the "board", so it fires an event when a child/element is removed from "outside"?

Comment: Are you trying to alert the board when someone drags something off of it? Do you want to notify the board if they drag it back on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Group.html#eventSummary
`remove`, `removed`, `elementRemove`, `elementAdd`